# Validating Close method and Windows Close button C#

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, click, formclosing

I am having a method like `MainPage_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)` and I am using Close method to close the form.
This this.Close() method also triggers the `MainPage_FormClosing` method.

I just want to perform some function specifically when the user click on Form Windows Close **Button**.

I have seen some other questions here, they used some way like `String.Equals((sender as Button).Name, @"CloseButton")` to validate.
The sender is always null for me

How can I validate this ?

Comment: Why would you want to do certain validation _only_ when the user is closing the form using a specific button? Shouldn't your form-closing validating happen whether the user clicks that button, or presses Ctrl+W, or presses a close button in the form's title bar (if it has one)?

Comment: The sender will be the form.  The e parameter in FormClosing has a CloseReason.  You can use that to see why the form is closing and act accordingly.

Comment: @LarsTech both CloseReason has the same value like `UserClosing`. So i couldn't validate it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use `e.CloseReason`, the simplest solution would be to use a flag - Have a form level boolean variable that will only change it's state if you are closing the form in code and in the form closing event handler. Something like this will do:

```
private bool _isClosedFromCode = false;
```

...

```
private void CloseForm()
{ 
    _isClosedFromCode = true;
    Close();
}
```

...

```
private void MainPage_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(_isClosedFromCode)
    {
        // do your stuff here
    }

   _isClosedFromCode = false; 
}
```